# HTTP - Access-Control-Allow-Origin multiple domains

Tags: http, http-headers, cors

Is it possible to send an **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** header with more than **1 domain**? If yes, how?
Seems like browsers do not accept multiple domains in this header appropriately.

Sending this header with an asterisk is not an option. I do not want to open it to everyone.

Comment: See this post for possible answers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40558069/2668852

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access-Control-Allow-Origin Multiple Origin Domains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653308/access-control-allow-origin-multiple-origin-domains)